# Java: synchronizing list

Tags: java, multithreading, list, synchronization

I have an ArrayList and I manipulate it ONLY within a synchronized block, should I use Collections.synchronizedList too?
Example:

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());    
// versus List list = new ArrayList();    
synchronized(list) {
      // my code
}
```

Comment: Only one will suffice. Use only `synchronizedList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you only access your list within `synchronized` blocks, you don't need `synchronizedList()`
- If you only access your list using elementary operations (`add()`, `remove()`, etc) and invocations of these operations don't depend on each other (i.e. atomicity is not an issue), you can use only `synchronizedList()` without explicit `synchronized` blocks
- If you want to be able to invoke elementary operations without `synchronized` blocks, but also have compound operations (including iteration) that should be atomic, you need both `synchronizedList()` and `synchornized` blocks for compound operations

Comment: Not-elementary operations are just iterations? I always and only see these examples, but not others, so, "just blocks for iterations"?

Comment: There can be compound operations that should be atomic too, such as `if (!list.contains(...)) list.add(...)`

Comment: @Tatanan, "Not elementary" means, any sequence of operations that temporarily leaves your data in an inconsistent/invalid/illegal state.  The classic example is a program that takes money out of one bank account and deposits it into another.  There is an instant, in-between the withdrawal and the deposit when the books are not correct.  If an auditor thread happens to look at the two accounts during that instant, it would report a violation.  Putting those two operations into a synchronized block makes them an atomic unit, and would prevent the auditor from seeing the accounts in that state.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the synchronized declaration, no need for the explicit synchronized block:

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
```

The only way to change the contents of the list is by invoking add or remove, which is now decorated with synchronized versions of those methods thanks to this declaration.

Comment: I thought the block was necessary for iterations, sorting and so on.
My doubt was actually only the declaration, if in case I put all my code wrapped, I would need to declare the list as synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

Using an explicit `synchronized` block and using `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList())` will work equivalently, with respect to mutual exclusion.  However, if you must iterate over the list returned by the call to `Collections`, you ***must*** explicitly synchronize on that list externally anyway, per the **java spec** (sorry, SO won't let me link to it here).

Another thing to consider is overhead.  `Collections.synchronizedList(List orig)` creates a new object that controls access to the original list implementation.  Depending on how often you plan to make this call, and how many different ways you access the original list object, you may be better off synchronizing it externally.